# Accessing local image file in Vue.js gives 404

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

I have a laravel+vue project where in a vue component I use a local image. But in the console I get an error message:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/[object%20Module] 404 (Not Found)
```

Apparantly vue cannot find the image and tries to GET it.

The code in the component:

```
<img
        src="../assets/images/bankje256x256.png"
        width="80"
        heigth="80"
        class="ttr"
        @click.prevent="addBankje"
      />
```

The image exists in the right folder.

It also exists (with the same name) in public/images.

Any suggestion what I might do wrong?

Added later:

In my public/js/app.js I find the following lines referring to the image:

```
/***/ "./resources/js/assets/images/bankje256x256.png":
/*!******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/js/assets/images/bankje256x256.png ***!
  \******************************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "default": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = ("/images/bankje256x256.png?15a10b5a25b8eeef99f27dff448e29b5");

/***/ }),
```

and

```
 _vm._v(" "),
        _c("img", {
          staticClass: "ttr",
          attrs: {
            src: __webpack_require__(/*! ../assets/images/bankje256x256.png */ "./resources/js/assets/images/bankje256x256.png"),
            width: "80",
            heigth: "80"
          },
          on: {
            click: function($event) {
              $event.preventDefault()
              return _vm.addBankje.apply(null, arguments)
            }
          }
        })
      ]),
```

Comment: Check the path of the image and the name and extension. And where is this vue file located which has the `<img>` tag?

Comment: The vue file is in resources/js/components. The image is in resources/js/assets/images

Comment: Ok Then there seems nothing wrong with the path. Try `:src="require('../assets/images/bankje256x256.png')"` instead.